# Checking differences between the fields in mysql database using Php

Tags: php, mysql, field

I am trying to determine if any differences exist between a number of fields between rows of a mysql database.

for example, if name field is different in one row echo a result out.

What is the best method for this?

**edit:**

for example

```
Name          AGE
john smith    68
john smith    68
John M Smith  68
```

I would like a script that detect the name in the third line is different to the others but to be able to do this for both name and age fields

Comment: Different as opposed to what? Compare which rows to which other rows? Best give some sample data with the expected result, otherwise it's unclear what you mean exactly.

Comment: please explain in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to think about: Different to what? You always have to define a value a column should have. If you want all rows which are not "john smith" with age 68, your statement would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name <> "john smith" AND age <> 68;
```

That will return all rows that are different to the defined values.

A very basic PHP code example would be the following:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name <> "john smith" AND age <> 68';

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        // do something with the results using $row['name'] and $row['age']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to group datasets where a certain deviance could be measured in the name, but the age must be equal?

So, if I have understood this correctly:
"Age" is not a reliable value, because people get older once in a year and the age gets obsolete. Use a birthdate.

"Name": 2 guys can be born at the same day. So more Data is needed to compare. If the Name is all you have, then you can utilize the "Levenshtein-Distance". This must be implemented with an stored procedure or you compute this with php...

Comment: the age and name are just example fields, I am just looking for a general check to see if different to each other or a previous entry for example

Comment: so for example, I have three fields all with an incrememental ID, Row 3 is different to the previous two. I need to be able to check trhough all rows and see which one is different etc

Comment: That where only assuptions I made to make the point more clear. You need enough data to get a clear conclusion if a dataset is similar enough, that it could be a duplicate of another one, or it is just totally different.